# How to catch if ajax got wrong response type with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, try-catch

My ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: self.options.base_url + '/interface/jsonp/auth_user/',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function (data) {
         self._after_user_auth(data);
     },
     error: function () {
         self._service_unavailable()
     }
 });

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Unhandled Exception</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Unhandled Exception</h1>
    <p>An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

And if there is some error on server-side I get the next response

which rises `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Is it possible to catch that on the client?

Comment: whats wrong in posting `_service_unavailable()?`

Comment: @captain ok, I see, _service_unavailable is fired (it just writes in logs about it, does nothing with exception itself) but I still get the error in my chrome's console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you, but you can catch JavaScript error with

`try{}catch(){}`:

```
$.ajax({
     url: self.options.base_url + '/interface/jsonp/auth_user/',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function (data) {
         try{
             self._after_user_auth(data);
         }catch(err){
             console.log(err); //catch is fired if inside try js find an error.
         }
     },
     error: function () {
         self._service_unavailable()
     }
});
```

`catch(err)` - err is an object that contain all error information.

some documentation: [Try catch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Comment: nope, it does not work ether as if you put the whole ajax call in try-catch statement, but thanks for your answer